# Let $x, y$ be positive integers. Find all values of $x$ and $y$ such that $y^2-(4x-5)\cdot 2^x = 2^2$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, integers

I've been trying that and found $(2,4)$, $(5,22)$, $(9, 126)$ are possible answers.
But it seems there should be a proof that they are the only answers or there could be more answers.

Grateful if anyone could give hints on giving a logical proof on finding all possible answers.
Thank you!!

Comment: Hint: $(y-2)(y+2) = (4x-5)2^{x}$, and $4x-5$ is odd, $gcd(y-2, y+2)=2$

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging to one side yields $$Y^2 = 4+2^x(4x-5) - 4(2^{x-2}(4x-5)+1)$$

We will assume here that $x \geq 4$, as the smaller cases can be checked easily.

Since $4$ is a square, we may cancel it out and rewrite $2y=Y$.

Thus, $$y=2^{x-2}(4x-5)+1$$

Rearranging and factorising yields $$(y-1)(y+1)=2^{x-2}(4x-5)$$

Notice that the RHS is even, and thus each term on the LHS must also even. Now, we also know that how the $(4x-5)$ term is always odd. Thus, we know that (WLOG) $y-1$ and $y+1$ contain $k$ and $x-2-k$ powers of 2 in their prime factorisation, respectively.

Now, if $k$ was chosen such that both $k$ and $x-2-k$ are greater than $1$, then both the two terms would be divisible by $4$. However, the two terms are only two apart, thus this cannot happen.

Since $x \geq 4$, the only possible values for $k$ are $0$ and $1$.

If $k=0$, then we can clearly see that one term recieves all of the powers of $2$. However, we can see that $2^{x-2} > (4x-5)+2$ (best case scenario) at 7 and beyond, thus only values of 6 and below needs to be checked.

If $k=1$, then we have that $2^{x-3} > 2(4x-5) + 2$ (best case scenario) being true at values 10 and beyond. Thus, we only need to check values of $x$ starting at $1$ and finishing at $9$.

Thus, the only values for $(x,y)$ are $(2,4),(5,22),(9,126)$.